# Построение графика, где одна ось это дни

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, график

Делаю парсер погоды и требуется график температуры на  неделю.Делаю в WinForm C#, график- Chart. Проблема в  том, что, если даты будут переходящими месяц (например 28,29,30,31,1,2,3), то будет, как на первом изображении. Как можно сделать нормально? Может использовать  другие элементы? Если да, то какие и как это реализовать?

[image][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 28 - это не дата. Дата - это день, месяц и год.

Comment: используйте: год * 12 + месяц * (нужен словарь количества дней в месяце)[месяц]  + день - день_с_которого_начинается_график